# Horrendous Scope of Text

Tags: knowledge, visual, steganography, outer-space, symbols

> w34rfvgy78i
>
> 34rtyhbvftyu89
>
> 567tgyhvbn
>
> 87654edft5cvbnmkiuhn
>
> ?
>
> w3edcr5tgby7ujmiokn
>
> dfgt67uhjkcvbnm
>
> w3edcr5tgby7ujm,>
>
> rgncgu9ik987
>
> w3edr5tgbnmkiuhbvc
>
> e5t6y7uxfvgbhn
>
> 4rfc7yhndfghj

***What name does the question mark represent?***

---

No cypher or decryption is involved, so don't worry about that if you were. This is likely to be easier than it looks. To start off, use the tags to help you out — they are *key* to solving this puzzle.

Good luck! :)

---

> **Edit 1:** So the astronomy tag is merged with the outer-space tag. It's specific to astronomy though, just as a heads-up.

> **Edit 2:** By the astronomy tag, I mean *astrology*. I created this puzzle on the belief that these two meant the same thing, but as shown in @[Smock](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/56669/smock)'s comment below, there is a distinct difference.

Comment: Why did the [tag:astronomy] tag seemingly automatically change to [tag:outer-space]? I specifically chose the former tag for a reason...

Comment: It is a [tag synonym](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/outer-space/synonyms).

Comment: Okay I'm gonna be a total smartass and say it. Pretty much any work transormation of words representing something else techinically needs decryption. Also, astronomy tag is merged with outer-space. You can't really do anything about that.

Comment: @North this is not decryption, because to solve the puzzle, you must not change any of the words or letters; you aren't really transforming anything, but only finding a different angle of looking at it. Also, this particular kind of astronomy is different. However, if I got into more detail, I would probably be spoiling the answer. I have given plenty of information already.

Comment: Oh okay :/. I got out smrt-assed XD You deserve an upvote for that!

Comment: @North ...I feel bad xD But thanks for the upvote :)

Comment: @noedne thanks for letting me know of that. I will keep that in mind in future puzzles  :P

Comment: Ahahaha don't feel bad, it's a good puzzle.

Comment: @North oh, that edit is better! Thank you for that! I'll go upvote some post of yours ;) **Edit:** ...in at least $19$ hours... stupid daily voting limit!

Comment: @user477343 I read that comment as vomiting limit. Also, you don't need to, I'm just here to help :P

Comment: To my mind there's a big difference between Astrology and Astronomy. This is not Astronomy: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Astrology_and_astronomy

Comment: @Smock I do not believe there is an astronomy tag, but before reading that article, I thought they were the same thing. Thanks for sharing your opinion on this!

Comment: I did notice the lack of an Astrology tag - perhaps there should be one? Although that might actually give the game away much more easily than outer-space?

Comment: @Smock an astrology tag might give my game away, but if someone else wants to use such a tag for *their* puzzle, the consequence might not be quite the same; besides, this puzzle has already been solved ;)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> The missing line is for Leo. The lines represent symbols for the signs of the zodiac drawn using the keys on a US keyboard as a raster. (I admit I did not go through all lines, so the deduction may be wrong.)

Comment: Nah, you got it correct. Well done! (A diagram would be useful, here, but eh... it's hard to come up with those.) Also, did you get the hint in the title? ;)

Comment: I only spotted it afterwards, but it may have helped subconsciously.

Comment: Well, I wish I could vote now... but I have reached my daily voting limit, and I have to wait at least $15$ hours before I can vote again, unfortunately... great answer, though! :D

Comment: @MOehm Yup! The eighth one needs a `>` at the end, though (hence why I put that in, albeit to type that symbol, I need to press `shift` first); but thank you very much for the diagrams! You can post that as a supporting answer, I guess! :P

Comment: Wow, that's really cool!

Comment: Well, I'll cautiously offer an image that illustrates the answer. If kovacsur likes, it can be used in the answer. Spoilers, obviously. [Here goes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J25WL.png).

Comment: Congratulations on your very first $\color{green}{\text{accepted}}$ answer! $\color{green}{\checkmark}$